# Отрендерить polymer внутри react

Tags: reactjs, polymer

Когда передаю по `properties` в `polymer`, он не получает данные

`React`

```
    render() { 
    return ( <div>
        <some-polymer width="300" height="200" data="1000"></some-polymer>
    </div> );
}
```

Вот эти данные не обновляется, после `render` в `react`

Comment: у вас вообще это работает?

Comment: через link,  подключаешь и работает, проект такой, засунули,  а теперь делать, что - не знаю

Comment: some-polymer это какой то кастомный тэг?

Comment: не думаю, что реактовский jsx движок знает про полимеровские кастомные теги?